# Can't call dynamic page with $_GET

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to use $_GET to call a dynamic page, but it throws "Error". Do I need to call page 1 from page 2 or why can't they talk to each other?
Thanks in advance for your help, supposingly there's an easy solution.
/Jimmy

This is page 1:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Players</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
<body>
<?php include ("header.php"); ?>   
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "jim";
$password = "pass";
$dbname = "jim";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
// SQL search
$sql = "SELECT PlayerID, Person FROM People where PlayerID is not null ORDER BY Person";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
// Condition
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Player</th></tr>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>"."<a href='spelarfakta.php?=id{$row['PlayerID']}'>{$row['PlayerID']}</a>"."</td>"."<td>".$row["Person"]."</td>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
  echo "No hits";
}
$conn->close();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

This is page 2:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Player Stats</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
<body>
<?php include ("header.php");   
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    echo '<p>'. $_GET['id'].'</p>';}
    else {echo 'Error';
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check the URLs you are creating there. You messed up the position of the `=`.

Comment: `=id` should be `id=`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I knew there would be an easy solution!

Comment: @CBroe sir you quickly find the right solution & post as comment not as answer why if you post as answer then you give the points.

Comment: @KUMAR this is the kind of minor issue the SO community rather does not want answers posted for in the first place, but rather see them closed as “[Not reproducible or] was caused by a typo”. (“While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers.”)

Comment: @CBroe sir ok thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Correct solution as a comment:

=id should be id=